# Safari can't open the page "localhost:3306". The error is: "Cancelled load from 'localhost:3306' because it is using HTTP/0.9."

Tags: mamp

I recently updated to MySQL 5.7.21 and MAMP 5, and when I try to load my Wordpress site, I received the error below:

Safari can't open the page "localhost:3306". The error is: "Cancelled load from 'localhost:3306' because it is using HTTP/0.9." (:0)

When I load 127.0.0.1, I am able to see a few aspects of the code, but most of the site is missing.

Details on my working environment:

macOS High Sierra
MySQL 5.7.21
MAMP basic 5
- Apache Port: 80
- MySQL Port: 3306
PHP 7.2.7
Wordpress Version: possibly 4.8.2 (hasn't been updated to latest version)

I looked at previous posts and have checked apache_error logs, mysql_error logs and php_error logs and here are the errors that I see in each:

**MySQL Error Logs (mysql_error.log)**

- From previous research, I don't believe this error would cause any issues, but I will include them anyway

[Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2018-08-03T09:25:38.283012Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21) starting as process 7654 ...
2018-08-03T09:25:38.286936Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive

**Apache Logs (apache_error.log)**

[Sat Aug 04 10:11:13 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Aug 04 10:11:13 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Aug 04 10:11:13 2018] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 1318)
[Sat Aug 04 10:11:13 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.7 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2o DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Aug 04 10:11:14 2018] [error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat Aug 04 10:11:14 2018] [error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

**PHP Error Logs (php_error.log)**

- these error log goes on for pages and pages; all stating that "table doesn't exist"
- I'm not sure why the formatting gets weird down below, please disregard the formatting

[03-Aug-2018 18:24:57 Asia/Kuala_Lumpur] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/knowledgebase/wp-content/plugins/hello.php:59
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/knowledgebase/wp-content/plugins/hello.php on line 59
[03-Aug-2018 14:00:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Database\Designer::getHtmlTableList() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/db_designer.php on line 190 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Database/Designer.php:290
Stack trace:

## 0 /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/db_designer.php(190): PhpMyAdmin\Database\Designer->getHtmlTableList(NULL, NULL)

## 1 {main}

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Database/Designer.php on line 290
[04-Aug-2018 01:17:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/feed/fetchFeed.php on line 19
[04-Aug-2018 01:17:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.mamp.info/feed/mac/MAMP/English/feed/home.json): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/feed/fetchFeed.php on line 19
[04-Aug-2018 03:36:04 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'knowledgebase.wp_users' doesn't exist for query CREATE TABLE wp_users (
  ID bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  user_login varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  user_pass varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  user_nicename varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  user_email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  user_url varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  user_registered datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  user_activation_key varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  user_status int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  display_name varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (ID),
  KEY user_login_key (user_login),
  KEY user_nicename (user_nicename),
  KEY user_email (user_email)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci made by wp_install, make_db_current_silent, dbDelta

**Apache2 Logs (mysqlid)**

2018-08-04T05:26:30.014732Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2018-08-04T05:26:30.014862Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.

- MySql isn't running multiple occurrences on my computer - according to Activity Monitor
- My ibdata1 file looks like complete gibberish - can't find anywhere if this is normal or corrupted

I've checked multiple files and support forums, and the closest I've gotten was getting an error that states - not sure how to recreate this part:

**500 Internal Server Configuration Error**

Is there any issue with my plugins? I think an update might have caused issues with the plugins I use. I can get a list of them if you need as well.
Please let me know any additional information you may need.

Comment: Port 3306 belongs to mysql. Why do you want to open it in your browser?

Comment: @Shadow When I click the link to open my webpage, it defaults to localhost:3306. I can't get into any Wordpress admin pages. The site isn't published yet - I'm still in the editing phase.

Comment: Did you tried `localhost:8080` ? And this seems to be more related with the MAMP configuration then the WP setup.

Comment: @ale yes I tried 8080 as well, but it still won't load... I also noticed that even though I type in "localhost," it always takes me to localhost:3306

Comment: Though old, to help readers, 
I saw the same error on Safari can't open the web page, "Cancelled load from .. because it is using HTTP/0.9." (:0). 
The issue was that server was sending *HTTP/2 200 OK* in response headers. Sending *HTTP/1.1 200 OK* worked. Apparently, Safari may be strict with Http version or any other header params

Comment: adding to @Guru_07: got the same safari error msg while writing my own server. My typo was I left no space between 200 and OK in my response to the client. Firefox chews that no problem, but Safari is too stuck-up for that and complains.